# Creating data frames in Spark using Sets in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a dummy data frame in Spark using Scala which looks like this -

```
+-----------+----+
|channel_set|rate|
+-----------+----+
|     [A, D]| 0.0|
|        [C]| 0.0|
|        [D]| 1.0|
|     [B, A]| 0.5|
+-----------+----+
```

I have tried below code to do that -

```
val b = Array((Set("A","D"),0.0) , (Set("C"),0.0), (Set("D"),1.0), (Set("B","A"),0.5) )
val dummy_data = sc.parallelize(b).toDF("channel_set", "rate")
```

But facing an error -

```
scala> val dummy_data = sc.parallelize(b).toDF("channel_set", "rate")
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String]
- field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Set", name: "_1")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
```

Kindly help.

Comment: `val b = Array((List("A","D"),0.0) , (List("C"),0.0), (List("D"),1.0), (List("B","A"),0.5) )

val dummy_data = sc.parallelize(b).toDF("channel_set", "rate")`

This works. Is it the correct approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is a *mutable object* and *dataframes/datasets* should have *static schema* i.e. *fixed dataTypes*. So use of `Seq` or `List` should work for you as they are immutables.

```
val df = Seq(
  (Array("A","D"),0.0),
  (Array("C"),0.0),
  (Array("D"),1.0),
  (Array("B","A"),0.5)
).toDF("channel_set", "rate")

df.show(false)
```

You should have dataframe as

```
+-----------+----+
|channel_set|rate|
+-----------+----+
|[A, D]     |0.0 |
|[C]        |0.0 |
|[D]        |1.0 |
|[B, A]     |0.5 |
+-----------+----+
```

Comment: can u explain where I was going wrong and why can't I create a Dataframe from Array ??

Comment: I need my "channel_set" column to contain sets of channels.

Comment: Arrays are mutables so can be used as elements only and not to create dataTypes. Thats why arrays won't work. And what do you mean by sets of channels? doesn't my answer helped you ?

Comment: You can use List instead of Seq as Lists are immutables as Seq. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your error message, it's the `Set` type that Spark's SQL/DataFrame API doesn't support:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
  No Encoder found for scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String]
```

Here's the [data types supported by Spark SQL/DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).  That said, you can use `Set` within a `UDF`, if needed.

In creating a DataFrame, Spark handles Seq, List, Array in a similar fashion.  If you do a `printSchema` and `show` on the following 3 DataFrames, you'll see that they're identical.

```
sc.parallelize(Array(
    (Array("A","D"),0.0) , (Array("C"),0.0), (Array("D"),1.0), (Array("B","A"),0.5)
  )).toDF("channel_set", "rate")

sc.parallelize(List(
    (List("A","D"),0.0) , (List("C"),0.0), (List("D"),1.0), (List("B","A"),0.5)
  )).toDF("channel_set", "rate")

sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (Seq("A","D"),0.0) , (Seq("C"),0.0), (Seq("D"),1.0), (Seq("B","A"),0.5)
  )).toDF("channel_set", "rate")

// res.printSchema
// root
//  |-- channel_set: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
//  |-- rate: double (nullable = false)

// res.show
// +-----------+----+
// |channel_set|rate|
// +-----------+----+
// |     [A, D]| 0.0|
// |        [C]| 0.0|
// |        [D]| 1.0|
// |     [B, A]| 0.5|
// +-----------+----+
```